# Angular2 Router data property on routes

Tags: angular, router

I got these routes in my app-routing module:

```
{
  path: 'some',
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  data: {
    auth: {
      test: "theTest"
    },
  },
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      component: SomeComponent,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      resolve: {
        something: SomethingResolver
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

In the AuthGuard `CanActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)` if I do a `console.log(route.data["auth"]` and get `{test: "theTest"}` twice.

Do children "adopt" data of parents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are duplicating things, `path : 'some'` and `path: ''` in the children array are pointing to the same route put the `canActivate: [AuthGuard]` only in the child so the `canActivate` will be executed only once:

```
{
  path: 'some',
  data: {
      auth: {
         test: "theTest"
      }
   },
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      component: SomeComponent,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      resolve: {
        something: SomethingResolver
      }
    },
  ]
}
```